# minimal rights needed to write powershell scripts

Tags: 2010, powershell, ssom, authorization

I got some CSOM scripts in a .Net Application, that I have to to move to the server, using the server object model/powershell. As our Sharepoint team has no time and skills, it was decided that I have to do this. My question is, how can we set up my authorization to fulfill this task? I am a site collection administrator and all the scripts refer to that site collection. Would it be enough, if I get remote login to the server? If possible I would like to avoid having any extra rights that I do not explicitly need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions to use the SSOM are highly privileged. If minimal permissions are a requirement you should stick to CSOM.

To use the SSOM you need to have shell admin permissions. See this [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596.aspx) article for full details.

Comment: Moving to the server has more weight, because we have items in the backlog that require accessing objects that are not available in CSOM. That's why I am looking for an option that lets development on the server, but restricts other rights to the target site collection. But, if I read it correctly: `However, the result of running this cmdlet is that the user specified with the UserName parameter will have the dbo_owner role access on the affected databases as described above. Therefore, you should carefully plan which users are given this access.`, it looks like an all or nothing option.

Comment: Indeed. Might be worth starting a new post explaining your problem to see if there are alternatives.